# How do hide contact form 7 validation errors and success message box?

Tags: css, wordpress

How do hide contact form 7 validation errors and success message box from form bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put below code in the css

```
.wpcf7-response-output {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, its work perfectly.