# Contact Us Form 7 - How to hide this particular one?

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

```html
<div class="klaviyo-cta">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8">
          <p class="heading-title"><strong>Join the</strong><br /> movement.</p>
          <div class="form-wrapper">
            <p class="sub-title">Stay current on our latest news, press, and partnerships.</p>  
            <div class="klaviyo-form-V649b2"></div>
            <?php //echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="242" title="Signup Form Footer"]'); ?>
              <p>
                  
              </p>
             <p class="sub-title">By signing up, you are giving your consent and agreeing to our 
                <b><a href="https://www.plasticcreditexchange.com/legal" style="color:white;"> Data Privacy Policy </a></b></p>
```

this is the exact nature of the problem
[this success message, is very odd and needs to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P8Or.png)

this success message appears right in the middle of the input box, some content is hidden, alignment is off and i dont want it to appear

I have tried - [How do hide contact form 7 validation errors and success message box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597941/how-do-hide-contact-form-7-validation-errors-and-success-message-box)

also this - [hide validation errors or success message box on contact form 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900149/hide-validation-errors-or-success-message-box-on-contact-form-7?newreg=866be1b460c748668acc6539cabdd2ea)

also tried 'additional.css' [this is from additional css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMhtf.png) and style.css

PS- the form im using is [contact-form-7 id="242" title="Signup Form Footer"]

```html
<div class="klaviyo-cta">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8">
          <p class="heading-title"><strong>Join the</strong><br /> movement.</p>
          <div class="form-wrapper">
```

Comment: The links you've included should provide you the information you need. We can't help you further unless you edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: just made edits, pls tell me if that works